# How to format SQL query using Pivot in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Find the images 1 and 2, I want result as image 2 using pivot SQL.

[Old table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdsOf.png)

[Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjp2x.png)

Comment: you can have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PermID,
ISNULL([New_User],0)as [New_User],ISNULL([Edit_User],0)as [Edit_User] ,ISNULL([Permission],0) as [Permission] ,ISNULL([Store-Credit],0)as [Store-Credit],ISNULL([Refund],0) as [Refund] ,ISNULL([Gift_Certificate],0)as [Gift_Certificate]
FROM
(SELECT PermID, Fname,'0' AS Active  
    FROM F3_BC_Users_Permissions_Master) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 max(Active)
FOR fname IN ([New_User],[Edit_User],[Permission],[Store-Credit],[Refund],[Gift_Certificate])
) AS PivotTable;
```